# Why do my nested if statements not iterate my int variable up by 1?

Tags: java, if-statement, java.util.scanner

#### What I'm trying to do

I want my if statement booleans to iterate the variable up when inputs are out of the range.

#### The problem

The numbers I input to be checked by the if statements don't seem to work. If the 3 inputted numbers are less than -6.0, or above 12.3 a failure is recorded, but the `int` variable I used never seems to change.

#### What I tried

Ive tried switching the order of the iteration and just using + 1, but the "failures" variable always stays at 0

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String input = "a";
        double aNum1;
        double aNum2;
        double aNum3;
        int aFailures = 0;


        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);


        //Trix
        while (true) {

            System.out.println("Please enter a command:");
            input = scnr.next();


            if (input.equals("a")) {

                System.out.println("Enter number 1:");
                aNum1 = scnr.nextDouble();
                System.out.println("Enter number 2:");
                aNum2 = scnr.nextDouble();
                System.out.println("Enter number 3:");
                aNum3 = scnr.nextDouble();

                if (aNum1 <= -6.0 && aNum1 >= 12.3) {
                    ++aFailures;
                }
                if (aNum2 <= -6.0 && aNum2 >= 12.3) {
                    ++aFailures;
                }
                if (aNum3 <= -6.0 && aNum1 >= 12.3) {
                    ++aFailures;
                }
            }
            if (input.equals("f")) {

                System.out.println("Azuview failures: " + aFailures);
                break;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

I expect the system to output "Azuview failures 2" when I input numbers outside of the Boolean condition but the program doesn't seem to recognise that the input is out of the range. "aFailures" begins at 0 but never changes from the if statements...

Comment: Try to think of a number which would cause `aNum1 <= -6.0 && aNum1 >= 12.3` to be true. I think you mean to use `||`.

Comment: Isn't your if conditions saying if aNum# is less than -6.0 AND greater than 12.3 ... how is that possible to ever be true? Should they be the other way around?

Comment: @MarsAtomic I don't really see how that's at all relevant.

Comment: Yeah, that was for a question I had open in another tab. I pulled back the vote, but the comment stayed.

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

The `&&` (AND) operator is being used in your `if` statement when you really should be using `||` (OR). `aNum1 <= -6.0 && aNum1 >= 12.3` will never evaluate to true because a number obviously cannot be less than or equal to -6.0 and greater than or equal to 12.3 at the same time.

As for the rest of your program, I've decided to use a `for` loop instead of using three separate ints to check the same condition three times.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "a";
    int aFailures = 0;

    Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Please enter a command:");
        input = scnr.next();

        if (input.equals("a")) {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
                System.out.println("Enter number " + i + ": ");
                double num = scnr.nextDouble();
                if (num <= -6.0 || num >= 12.3)
                    aFailures++;
            }
        } else if (input.equals("f")) {
            System.out.println("Azuview failures: " + aFailures);
            break;
        }
    }
    scnr.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you use `&&` (logic AND) instead of `||` (logic OR).

I have condensed your code a bit and now we ask 3 times for a number, if the number is in the range, we do nothing, else, we iterate `aFailures`.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    private static boolean checkRange(double input){
        return input <= -6.0 || input >= 12.3;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String input;
        int aFailures = 0;

        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (true) {

            System.out.println("Please enter a command:");
            input = scnr.next();


            if (input.equals("a")) {

                for(int i = 1; i <= 3; i++){
                    System.out.println("Enter number "+ i + ":");
                    if (Main.checkRange(scnr.nextDouble())) {
                        aFailures++;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (input.equals("f")) {

                System.out.println("Azuview failures: " + aFailures);
                break;

            }
        }
    }
}
```